# YA Science Fantasy (Fiction?) novel from the 80s

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I found this book at about the same time I found Glory Lane by Alan Dean Foster and the kid's retelling of Beowulf by Robert Nye. It was on the YA Science Fantasy shelf. It was about 1984 or after. It wasn't a best selling book so I am having trouble finding it again.  It was about space travel.  The main character had golden winged (mag lev?) sandals that overheated at one point.  She was able to see in space and navigate/pilot a ship, not many could do this. (You had to have extraordinary math skills.)  To do so she went into a sensory deprivation tank and something plugged into the back of her head/her brain. One of her friends was named Beauxtiffe (sp?)  pronounced BOW teef.  I'd just like to revisit the book if anyone has any clue what book this is I would be glad!

Comment: Note that *Glory Lane* wasn't out until 1987, so the date may be somewhat later than 1984.